# Start next batch process automatically

Tags: 7, batch-operations

Is it possible to start next batch_set() after finishing first one?
I've some import functionality which includes 4 steps. The next step takes data processed from first batch process so this is consecutive process which needs to be run one after one.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using Core drupal tools. Although I suspect different than your current approach.

I use a drupal Queue. and I fill it with items:

```
                                                    Queue
          Task1Items              Task2Items          Task3Items              Task4Items
    [---item1---item2---item3|item4---item5---item6|item7---item8---item9|item10---item11---item12]
```

I put all the tasks, in the ordering for the various `steps` of your task into a Queue. Then be sure to use a [Drupal Reliable Queue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7):

> There are two kinds of (default) queue backends available: reliable, which
>   preserves the order of messages and guarantees that every item will be
>   executed at least once. The non-reliable kind only does a best effort
>   to preserve order in messages and to execute them at least once but
>   there is a small chance that some items get lost. For example, some
>   distributed back-ends like Amazon SQS will be managing jobs for a
>   large set of producers and consumers where a strict FIFO ordering will
>   likely not be preserved. Another example would be an in-memory queue
>   backend which might lose items if it crashes.

After inserting all the items. Your batch call simply iterates over the queue you've populated. Use something like [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) to setup a group of task workers, or Background Process, or [Ultimate Cron Queue Scalar](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron_queue_scaler) to speedup your workload if you want.

Another handy module to view your queue visually is the [Queue UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/queue_ui) module. As the core Queue API is a developer API and has no UI by itself. Don't want to write php code to create/manage a queue -- look at [Rules Queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_queue).